# The alias name RANK() function is not recognized in the where clause with DISTINCT columns

Tags: sql, distinct, amazon-redshift, dense-rank

I have 2 tables with columns (customer, position, product ,sales_cycle, call_count , cntry_cd , owner_cd , cr8) and I am facing some challenges as mentioned below Kindly please help me to fix this

**My Requirement**

I have 2 tables   test.table1 and test.table2

I need to insert values form "test.table2" by doing an select with "test.table1". But I am facing a problem  i.e. I am getting some duplicates while loading data to "test.table2"

I have totally 8 columns in both the table but while loading I need to take the highest rank of the column "call_count" with condition of unique values of these columns (customer, position, product ,sales_cycle)

**Query what I tried**

```
select 
distinct (customer, position, product ,sales_cycle), 
rank () over (order by call_count desc) rnk, 
cntry_cd, 
owner_cd, 
cr8 
from test.table1 
where rnk=1
```

**I am facing few challenges in the above query (The database I am using is RedShift)**

1.I can't do distinct for only few columns

2.The alias name "rnk" is not recognized  in the where clause

Kindly please help me to fix this , Thanks

Comment: I'm confused. Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using "Red shift" database this is like PostgreSQL

Comment: then  remove the mysql tag and add  postgreSQL

Comment: Thanks , Yes I have changed the tag

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT**  a function. The parentheses around the column names simply create a single column with an anonymous record, they do not change the behaviour of the `distinct` operator which always operates on **all** columns in the select list. In Postgres you'd probably want `distinct ON ()`  - but I don't know if Redshift supports that (although Redshift is based on a very old version of Postgres it is a very different thing)

Comment: Thanks for your information about the distinct and how about the alias name of RANK() is not accepted by the where clause any mistake I am doing in that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use a column alias on the same level where it's introduced. You need to wrap the query in a derived table. The `distinct` as shown is useless as well if you use `rank()`

```
select customer, position, product, sales_cycle, 
       cntry_cd, owner_cd, cr8 
from (
  select customer, position, product, sales_cycle, 
         cntry_cd, owner_cd, cr8,
         rank () over (order by call_count desc) rnk
  from test.table1 
) t 
where rnk=1;
```

The derived table adds no overhead to the processing time. In this case it is merely syntactic sugar to allow you to reference the column alias.